SSIS "No data supplied for parameters" Error migrating from SQL Server to MySQL
I'm currently attempting to migrate a database table from my local SQL Server to a cloud-based MySQL database (SingleStore). As a preliminary test, I've created a simplified test table with a single integer column containing one row with the value 1. However, when running the SSIS Data Flow Task for this basic setup, I encounter the following error:

Error: 0xC020844B at Data Flow Task, ADO NET Destination [2]: An exception has occurred during data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 9.0(a) Driver][mysqld-5.7.32]No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement
Error: 0xC0047022 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "ADO NET Destination" (2) failed with error code 0xC020844B while processing input "ADO NET Destination Input" (9). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Setup and Steps Taken
Table Structure: Both the source and destination tables have identical columns and data types (an integer column named nu).
Components: I’m using a Data Flow Task with an OLE DB Source to connect to SQL Server and an ADO.NET Destination for the MySQL target. Both components connect successfully to their respective databases.
SQL Mode Adjustment: To address quotation issues, I included an Execute SQL Task before the Data Flow Task, running the following command on the destination database:
SET sql_mode= 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,ANSI_QUOTES';

This step completes without errors.
Data Source Modes: I’ve tested the OLE DB Source component using both "Table or view" and "SQL Command" data source modes.
In ADO.NET Destination, I clicked on the new for "Use a table or view" to create a new table in the destination. This way I could overcome the errors thrown because of quotation issues. I also made sure the table doesn't exist in the destination before start running the SSIS package. I used below query:
create table test (
nu int);

The mapping in the ADO.NET Destination Editor is correctly configured, and the preview successfully displays the table in the destination. The table is also successfully created in MySQL, ruling out privilege issues (I’m connected as an admin user).
Despite these configurations, the destination table remains empty, and the SSIS Data Flow Task fails with the error noted above. The error suggests a problem with parameters in the prepared statement, but there seems to be no discrepancy in column names or data types between source and destination.
I also tried ODBC Destination which I could not make its mapping right. The column names would not get displayed in the destination side.

Unfortunately, I do not see how we can help you from a programming point of view. The dba sister site of SO can probably provide you with the help you need with database migrations.

I suggest you change a tool to complete the migration, such as mysql workbench, which is more compatible.

I'm transferring from SQL SERVER to MySQL. There are definitely other approaches, however I'd like to understand this issue and why it's happening.

Recently, there are so many strange people on StackOverflow.
